# React - Navigation Prompt onConfirm gets triggered straight away

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-props

I have an issue where I need to show a navigationPrompt when use tries to re-route (that works).
But the onConfirm function gets called immediately before I hit the "Confirm" button.
I want to `setReload(true)`AFTER the user presses the "confirm" button.

```
<NavigationPrompt onConfirm={setReload(true)} when={myExampleFunction}>
                    {({ onConfirm, onCancel }) => (
                        <React.Fragment>
                            <Modal
                                ariaHideApp={false}
                                style={customStyles}
                                isOpen={true}
                            > You are about to lose all the data
            <button onClick={onCancel}>Cancel</button>
                                <button onClick={onConfirm}>Confirm</button>
                            </Modal>
                        </React.Fragment>
                    )}
                </NavigationPrompt>
```

Comment: Pls post your on Confirm function

Comment: onConfirm is already in my code.  `onConfirm={setReload(true)}` that's sent down as a prop to the modal. `{({ onConfirm, onCancel }) =>`  then in my modal I use it like this `<button onClick={onConfirm}>Confirm</button>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `setReload` with `setReload(true)` on mount.

You need to pass a function, and not call it there:

```
onConfirm={() => setReload(true)} // A new function to be called onConfirm
```

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. It seems to take me to the popup now, however, it doesn't actually setReload(true).